# jQuery calculate value on Text_Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes.

- Price
- Percent
- Result

I want to display result on Result textbox when value of Price textbox or Percent is change.

The formula is very easy but I don't know what it doesn't work !

```
Result = Percent/100 * price
```

Percent just can be between values 0 to 9 .
I wrote this code . where is the problem from ?

```
  var textbox = $("#<%= txtTaxPercent.ClientID %>");
            var ResultTextbox = $("#<%= txtfctTaxValue.ClientID %>");
            var PriceTextbox = $("#<%= txtPurePrice.ClientID %>");
            $(textbox).keydown(function (e) {
                var Result1;
                Result1 = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val());
                ResultTextbox.val('');
                ResultTextbox.val(Result1);
            });
            $(PriceTextbox).keydown(function (e) {
                var Result2;
                Result2 = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val());
                ResultTextbox.val('');
                ResultTextbox.val(Result2);
            });
```

Comment: *"I don't know what it doesn't work"* **How** does it not work? Does nothing happen? Do you get `NaN` in the boxes? A number, but the wrong one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is that you want `change` rather than `keydown`. **Edit**: Actually, you probably want `change`, `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` just to cover your bases, since `change` doesn't fire until you leave the field; depends how immediate you want to be. You can also throw `paste` in there, as some browsers may support that. Possibly even `blur` to be sure that regardless of how they changed the value, if they leave the field you recalc.

Also, there's no reason to call `val()` with an empty string, just to turn around and call it with your result. The second call will always overwrite the value written by the first call. And there's no need to call `$()` a second time on a jQuery object. So:

You can also condense the code a bit. So:

```
var textbox = $("#<%= txtTaxPercent.ClientID %>");
var ResultTextbox = $("#<%= txtfctTaxValue.ClientID %>");
var PriceTextbox = $("#<%= txtPurePrice.ClientID %>");
$([textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("change keyup keydown paste blur", function(e) {
    var Result;
    Result = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val(), 10);
    ResultTextbox.val(Result);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyixa5) (in the code there, naturally I've had to take out the ASP.Net stuff)

That `$([textbox[0], ResultTextbox[0]])` bit is tricky: I'm creating an array of raw DOM elements from two raw elements, the element at index `0` of `textbox` and the element at index `0` of `PriceTextbox`, then passing that into `$()` to wrap them in a jQuery object.

I've used [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) to bind multiple events, to cover our bases.

As @diEcho pointed out, I've also added the radix argument to `parseInt`. It's almost always best to supply a radix (unless you explicitly want to allow people to type things like "0xfe" for 254).

Comment: @T.J.Please change the `parseInt` to  `parseInt(xxx,10)`

Answer (score 2):

try with `change` on both textbox anytime and also use `live` with **multiple selector**

*raw code* ( just the logic)

```
var textbox = $("#<%= txtTaxPercent.ClientID %>");
var ResultTextbox = $("#<%= txtfctTaxValue.ClientID %>");
var PriceTextbox = $("#<%= txtPurePrice.ClientID %>");

$([ textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0] ]).live('change',function (e) {
    var Result1;
    Result1 = (parseFloat(textbox.val()) / 100) * parseInt(PriceTextbox.val(),10);
    ResultTextbox.val(Result1);
});
```

**References**

### [jQuery Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

### [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

### [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `live` call isn't doing what you think it is. You're passing two jQuery objects into it. That's not a signature listed in the docs, hard to know what will happen (and it will be unspecified behavior anyway).

Comment: @T.J. cant we use multiple selector???  either we can use `||` instead of `,` am i right??

Comment: @diEcho: You can use multiple *selectors*, within a single string. But you're passing multiple discrete arguments into the function. (No, you can't use `||` there.) So you can either do what I did in my answer -- `$([textbox[0], PriceTextbox[0]]).` -- or re-list the IDs in one selector string with a comma: `$("#<%= txtTaxPercent.ClientID %>, #<%= txtPurePrice.ClientID %>").` But the problem with the second way is you're repeating the lookup, so the array way, though tricky looking, is more efficient.

Comment: @diEcho please change the parseInt to get parseInt(xxx,10), always use parseInt on base 10.

Comment: And `change` probably doesn't quite do what he wants (I only just now realized), since it doesn't fire until you leave the field.

Comment: he need to change the field, otherwise how do he write in both text box

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be keyUp and not keyDown because at keydown `textbox.val()` will not give you latest value. Also, in order to cover all the other scenerios, i think you will have to use keypress and paste function also.

Below is the code which i wrote for allowing only numeric values in a textbox. You can get an idea from it.

```
function CheckNumeric() {
    $('.IsNumeric')
    .keydown(function(event) {
        var key = event.which;
        if (event.shiftKey == true)
            return (key == 36 || key == 35 || key == 39 || key == 37 || key == 9);
        else//When SHIFT key is not down
            return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 46 || key == 36 || key == 35 || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
    }).bind('paste', function(event) {
        return (!isNaN(clipboardData.getData("text")));
    }).keyup(function(event) {
        var _Value = $(event.target).val();
        var _OldValue = $(event.target).val();
        for (var iCount = 0; iCount < _OldValue.length; iCount++) {
            if (_Value.charAt(0) == 0) {
                _Value = _Value.substring(1, _Value.length);
                $(event.target).val(_Value);
            }
        }
    }).focusout(function(event) {
        var _Value = $(event.target).val();
        var _OldValue = $(event.target).val();
        for (var iCount = 0; iCount < _OldValue.length; iCount++) {
            if (_Value.charAt(0) == 0) {
                _Value = _Value.substring(1, _Value.length);
                $(event.target).val(_Value);
            }
        }
    }).keypress(function(event) {
        var _Value = $(event.target).val();
        var _OldValue = $(event.target).val();
        for (var iCount = 0; iCount < _OldValue.length; iCount++) {
            if (_Value.charAt(0) == 0) {
                _Value = _Value.substring(1, _Value.length);
                $(event.target).val(_Value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with just 
`textbox.keydown(...`
and
`PriceTextBox.keydown(...`
No dollar sign no parenthesis.

Comment: It's true that he doesn't need to call `$()` on those, but doing so is harmless (other than wasting a tiny bit of processing time and memory). It's not going to be the problem in any case.